# Open v-select options on button click

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I am looking for a way to open vuetify v-select component when clicking on an icon button.
The v-select should not been seen when its closed, Only when opened by clicking on the button.
Its like sort of having The button toggling the state of the v-select

The purpose its to filter columns to show on data-table, And the reason i want it to be hidden by default its because i already have an v-select component at the table toolbar to select data to show.

I only have this is my relevant code, I don`t have any other idea how to continue from here

```
 <v-btn small icon>
      <v-icon>
        mdi-pencil
          <v-select :items="headers"></v-select>
      </v-icon>
 </v-btn>
```

Comment: I’m not even sure if you can actually nest a clickable element inside another.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution: create a variable *(which is named `toggleSelect` in this example)* that will control the visibility of the `<v-select/>` and its `<v-menu/>` (the dropdown options). `<v-select/>` has [`menu-props`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#api) which we can use control the menu's visibility. For the select field, we can simply use `v-if` to hide it.

```html
<v-btn 
  ...
  @click="toggleSelect = !toggleSelect"
>
  <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<v-select
  :items="headers"
  v-if="toggleSelect"
  :menu-props="{value: toggleSelect}"
/>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  headers: [...],
  toggleSelect: false,  // let's not show the <v-select/> at first load.
})
```

Here is a sample [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-resonance-nosgh?file=/src/components/Playground.vue) with `<v-data-table/>` implementation.

Comment: .v-select {
  opacity: 0;
}